# Using a Vector Index within a Function

Tags: r, vector

Trying to create a function that will generate a list/vector of days it took to accumulate thermal units.

```
Day<-c(1:10)
min1<-c(0.70,1.45,2.22,2.98,3.75,4.50,5.02,5.34,5.61,5.81)
data<-as.data.frame(cbind(Day,min1))
```

The following function correctly outputs the day on which data$min1 exceeded 2:

```
days.till<-function (x) min(data$Day[data$min1>=x])
days.till(2)
```

But if I attempt to use several x values, I get an error.

```
days.till(2:4)
[1] 4
Warning message:
In data$min1 >= x :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

The following strategies return the same error:

```
days.till(c(2:4))

days.till<-function (x=2:4) min(data$Day[data$min1>=x])
```

I've had no problem using multiple input values in other simpler functions so I fear the vector index within the function is causing the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could wrap your function in `Vectorize`: `Vectorize(days.till)(2:4)`

Comment: BTW, check out `findInterval` as it will be a lot faster for such cases: `findInterval(2:4, data$min1) + 1`

Comment: @alexis_laz you should add this as an answer (with microbenchmark results) -- it's definitely a lot faster and just as simple as the other posted solutions

Comment: @josilber : I've already posted a `findInterval` solution to their other similar question and it doesn't seem to have been taken into consideration; it'll feel like I'm pursuing them to use `findInterval` despite their will! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sapply` to calculate the desired value for each element in the passed vector:

```
days.till <- function(x) sapply(x, function(y) min(data$Day[data$min1>=y]))
days.till(2:4)
# [1] 3 5 6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Day<-c(1:10)
min1<-c(0.70,1.45,2.22,2.98,3.75,4.50,5.02,5.34,5.61,5.81)
mydata<-as.data.frame(cbind(Day,min1))

days.till <- function(x,data=mydata) {
  if (length(x)==1){
    return(min(data$Day[data$min1>=x]))
  } else if (length(x)>1) {
    return(lapply(x,days.till,data=data))
  }
}

## > days.till(2)
## [1] 3
## > days.till(2:4)
## [[1]]
## [1] 3

## [[2]]
## [1] 5

## [[3]]
## [1] 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modified version of your function:

```
days.till <- function(thresh)
  with(data, Day[sapply(thresh, function(x) which(min1 >= x)[1])])

days.till(2:4) 
# [1] 3 5 6
```